# Deciding a Big-O notation for an algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, big-o

I have questions for my assignment. 
I need to decide what is the Big-O characterization for this following algorithm:

[image]

I'm guessing the answer for Question 1 is O(n) and Question 2 is O(log n), but I kinda confused 
how to state the reason. Are my answers correct? And could you explain the reason why the characterization is like that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to determine this. The algorithm's Big-O performance **is what it is** regardless of your decision.

Comment: Your guess is quite correct and Q1 is simple,for Q2-try searching about binary search complexity!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place to ask others to do your homework! If you have a specific problem that you already tried hard to solve, but could not, we'll help if you can state your problem as a question.

Comment: I would recommend forming a study group in your class .. and going to talk with your Professor ..

Answer (score 2):

Question 1 : `O(n)` because it increments by constant (1).
first loop `O(n)` second loop also `O(n)`
total   `O(n) + O(n) = O(n)`

Question 2 : `O(lg n)` it's binary search.

it's `O(lg n)`, because problem halves every time.

if the array is size `n` at first second is `n/2` then `n/4` ..... `1`.

`n/2^i = 1` => `n = 2^i` => `i = log(n)` .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your answers are right.The first one is pretty simple. 2 *separate* `for` loops. So effectively its `O(n)`.

The second one is actually tricky. You are actually dividing the input size by 2 (half), that would effectively lead to a time complexity of `O(log n)`.